# Google Chrome notification works, but with wired message

Tags: google-chrome, push-notification, push

I need your help with Google notifications sending which works correctly but with empty messages, title, message etc. are missing...

Any ideas ?

Here is picture how it looks like:
[image: pic]

```php
define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', 'AIzaSyBBh4ddPa96rQQNxqiq_qQj7sq1JdsNQUQ' );
//$registrationIds = array( $_GET['id'] );
$user_device_key = 'eVuuhJNB3vs:APA91bGyf2iAcDEHMVe8MmYzUmNAVl08tfP4wHQFi0sIMhtlZ9PwljdEfZ8JhtfJ_O0rhXTvdJEiVbeRJaUfWn2qvHG6Gw7OjV2jSCmkUd1HK93dyocyC26_48xb0srxa5imUpqXSxMk';
$payload_info = create_payload_json("I know how to send push notifications!");

 // API access key from Google API's Console
        define('API_ACCESS_KEY', 'AIzaSyAjcvboyovxihsZBtrs2FmVkFbLs-bNk1k');
        // prep the bundle
        $msg = array
        (
            'message' => json_decode($payload_info)->aps->alert,
            'title' => 'This is a title. title',
            'subtitle' => 'This is a subtitle. subtitle',
            'tickerText' => 'Ticker text here...Ticker text here...',
            'vibrate' => 1,
            'sound' => 1,
            'largeIcon' => 'large_icon',
            'smallIcon' => 'small_icon'
        );
        $fields = array
        (
            'registration_ids' => array($user_device_key),
            'data' => $msg
        );
        $headers = array
        (
            'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        );
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL,                     'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send' );
        curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
        curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
        curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false );
        curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
        curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
        echo $fields;
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

    return $result > 0;


function create_payload_json($message) {
    //Badge icon to show at users ios app icon after receiving notification
    $badge = "0";
    $sound = 'default';
    $payload = array();
    $payload['aps'] = array('alert' => $message, 'badge' => intval($badge),'sound' => $sound);
    return json_encode($payload);
    }
```